# hoverColor property of the Raised button class in Flutter, doesn't change?

Tags: flutter, dart

Edit: I am using the IOS simulator, the following issue may not be persistent across all platforms.

I am under the impression that when creating a RaisedButton, it is possible to change the color of the button when the cursor hovers over the button.

However this does not appear to be the case.

// Create button

```
RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    color: Colors.redButtonBackgroundColo
    textColor: Colors.white,
    disabledColor: Colors.disabledRedButtonBackgroundColor,
    disabledTextColor: Colors.white,
    disabledElevation: 4,
    elevation: 4,
    hoverColor: Colors.redHoveredOverButtonColor, //<--- Here is where I would like to change the button color (to a slightly lighter shade.)
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),      
 ),
```

Thanks in advance for any help you may provide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the question is not very clear I am going to assume a few things.
First, you are running the app on **flutter desktop** or **web**. 
In that case, the code should work perfectly fine.

If you are trying it on mobile, then **there is no hover action on mobile**, that's why the button would not change its color.

If you want to change the color on tap, then you can **wrap the RaisedButton** with a **GestureDetector** and **use the onTap or onPanDown callback** to manually change the color of the button.